# Connection between regular elements of a Lie algebra and the Jordan normal form

Tags: lie-algebras, jordan-normal-form, online-resources

I need a source fornthe following statement:

If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a subalgebra of $\mathrm{Mat}_n$, an element $X$ is regular if and only if its Jordan normal form contains a single Jordan block for each eigenvalue.

I know that tbis is true for a complex $\mathfrak{g}$, but I need a source. I am also interested in that statement for a real Lie algebra (Jordan normal form still over the complex numbers).

Comment: A reference is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_element_of_a_Lie_algebra), e.g., the book of Fulton Harris.

Comment: I had a look, but was not able to find such a statement in this book.